# How to add prefix before token in request using drf-yasg or drf-spectacular

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, backend

I need add prefix "Token" before token in request header when using drf-yasg or drf-spectacular to create django drf API doc.

I have tried multiple tests:

1. Middleware:

[image]

2. SWAGGER_SETTINGS

[image]

3)SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS:

[image]

4. Token plus token in authorize form:

[image]

Url configs:

[image]

Options 1), 2) and 3) the request headers are:

[image]

and with 4) return 401 http status code

with the options 1), 2), 3) I receive 401 ""Authentication credentials were not provided." and with 4) invalid token

Can you help me please?